# How to print JSON with keys in numeric order (i.e. as if the string keys were integers)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON

```
{
    "clips": { 
        "0": {
            "name": "Please", 
            "id": 1, 
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "Print", 
            "id": 2 
        },
        "10": {
            "name": "me", 
            "id": 3 
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "in order", 
            "id": 4 
        }
    }
}
```

This is made like so:

`print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4))` which is great because it prints the keys in alphanumeric order.  However, I need these printed in actual numeric order, so above the key `"2"` to come before the key `"10"`.

I know that python usually doesn't sort keys in a dictionary, but I need to do this as the json will actually be read by humans and ordering it would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you basically trying to sort a dictionary after it has been converted from the JSON?

Comment: Can't JSON handle integer keys?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, `json` always [converts keys to strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 but isn't that *after* the `sort_keys`?

Comment: I'm not sure which occurs first, but it looks like it's the string conversion.

Comment: @ytpillai I am trying to print an already in existence dictionary to a file in that order.

Comment: OK, well, what you can do is make a new dictionary whose keys are the ordered keys of the original dictionary. Then, get the value of each of the keys from that original dictionary and print them out

Comment: As @zveryansky points out in [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/31350283/20789), what you are showing is **not actually valid JSON**, because you have extra commas (`,`) prior to the closing braces (`}`). Where did this fake-JSON come from?

Comment: @DanLenski you are right, thanks for pointing that out. I made a subset of my json to fit it all on the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension trick:

```
import json

d = dict({'2':'two', '11':'eleven'})
json.dumps({int(x):d[x] for x in d.keys()}, sort_keys=True)
```

Output:

```
'{"2": "two", "11": "eleven"}'
```

Comment: I didn't know that dictionary comprehension also exists. Thanks for teaching me something new as well :)

Comment: Also, why does dumping an integer key result in a string in the JSON?

Comment: @ytpillai integer keys aren't allowed so I believe the Python module automatically converts them.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordKeys = sorted([int(x) for x in originalDict.keys()])

newDict = OrderedDict()
for key in ordKeys:
    newDict[str(key)] = originalDict[str(key)]

#Print out to JSON
```

Comment: Beats me... this is the obvious best answer.

Comment: Please fix str(x) to str(key); Also: if one uses sort_keys=True in the following json.dump, this order will again be scrambled even for the OrderedDict [sic!]

Answer (score 1):

how about this one:

```
import json
import collections
a = '''
    {"clips": 
        { 
        "0":{"name": "Please", "id": 1,},
        "1": {"name": "Print", "id": 2,},
        "10": {"name": "me", "id": 3,},
        "2": {"name": "in order", "id": 4,}
    }}
'''

#replace comas before } otherwise json.loads will fail
a = a.replace(',}','}')

#parse json
a = json.loads(a)

#converting keys to int
a['clips'] = {int(k):v for k,v in a['clips'].items()}

#sorting
a['clips'] = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(a['clips'].items()))

print a
```

Comment: Why are you using such an odd approach to generating the JSON text? Why not simply use triple-quoted multi-line strings delimited with `'''` or `"""`?